# How to enable the eclipselink static weaving in spring boot along with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, eclipselink

1. Involve the https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jamgo.eclipselink-plugin
2. Check the log 
   [EL Warning]: metadata: ServerSession(1559673372)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [copyCustomer] for the entity class [class com.hybris.caas.order.model.Order] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.

```java
   @Configuration
public class JpaConfig extends JpaBaseConfiguration {

   protected JpaConfig(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties,
                       ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManagerProvider,
                       ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers) {
       super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManagerProvider, transactionManagerCustomizers);
   }

   @Override
   protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
       return new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
   }

   @Override
   protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
       final HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
       props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, detectWeavingMode());
       return props;
   }

   private String detectWeavingMode() {
       return "static";
   }

   /**
    *
    * @param entityManagerFactory
    * @return
    */
   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
       final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
       return transactionManager;
   }

}
```

```java
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.org.jamgo:eclipselink-plugin:0.2.2"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.jamgo.eclipselink-plugin"
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this plugin and it's capabilities but this is possible with pure Gradle without plugins.

There are 3 steps to do in order to make this work:

- Copy the persistence.xml file into the source folder next to the classes
- Do the weaving
- Remove the `persistence.xml` file from the classes source folder to avoid duplicate `persistence.xml` conflicts on the classpath

Also, it's very important to hook the process up into the compileJava task's last step in order to not break Gradle's up-to-date check.

For a more detailed explanation, check out my article on it: [EclipseLink static weaving with Gradle](https://arnoldgalovics.com/eclipselink-static-weaving-gradle/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=eclipselink-static-weaving-gradle).